# wait for callback of getJSON finish in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, getjson

I has something like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and JS:

```
function getData(id) {
    $.getJSON('url/to/jsondata',{id: id}, function(data) {
         /** append some data to div#content  **/
         $('#content').data('key', 'value');
     });
```

then I want to get data of #content in script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData(1); // run getData with some id
    console.log($('#content').data('key'));
});
```

Problem is console.log not run after callback of getJSON finish, so i get a undefined value in log.
Which is right way to make it work?
Thank!

Comment: @TheZ your comment is an answer - you should put it as one so it can get voted up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the deffered object from the ajax function and use the always, done or fail methods on it:

```
function getData(id) {
    return $.getJSON('url/to/jsondata',{id: id}, function(data) { //return this
         $('#content').data('key', data);
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData('content').always(function() { //is returned as deffered object
        console.log($('#content').data('key')); //runs when ajax completed
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already defined the callback in your `getJSON` call. To get the results put your console.log code near in the same function as the `/** append some data to div#content **/` comment.

Here's the jQuery documentation for getJSON so you can see which is the correct argument and how you can lay it out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer, +1 from me =)

Comment: @Mario No worries, you've got example code which always helps when all else fails!

Comment: @TheZ+Mario: console.log just for check which value i got. I want to use $('#content').data('key') for a while loop like this: `while($('#content').data('key') < someValue) { var id = newID; getData(id); }`

Answer (score -1):

You should put the log-call in the callback-function like this:

```
function getData(id) {
    $.getJSON('url/to/jsondata',{id: id}, function(data) {
         /** append some data to div#content  **/
         $('#content').data('key', 'value');

         console.log($('#content').data('key'));
     });
```